# Как получить числовое значение php error_reporting?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Приветствую, разработчики!

Возникла необходимость прописать через .htaccess значение `error_repoting`, поскольку прямого доступа к php.ini на сервере нет. Но данное значение в .htaccess задается как битовая маска.

Каким образом получить нужное битовое значение для набора именованных констант (например: `E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE`)?

С уважением, Александр.

Comment: echo decbin(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

Comment: @alexkad, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: работает вариант

    echo bindec(decbin(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE));

Gedweb, спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: @alexkad 
> echo bindec(decbin(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE));

Не видите себя, как индус!

     echo E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE;

Comment: @alexkad, 

    echo bindec(decbin(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE)); 

==

    echo E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE;

Comment: @romeo, @Etki  Да, правильно. Как всегда, все очень просто).

Answer (score 2):

Вроде бы apache позволяет ввод как в 10-й форме, так и константами:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag display_errors on
    php_value error_reporting 7   
    # или константами php_value error_reporting "E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE"
</IfModule>
```

Также Вам никто не мешает [сделать это в PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.error-reporting.php):

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE); 
// эквивалент ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
```

Обычно второй вариант с PHP является предпочтительнее.

Comment: Дело в том что .htaccess принимает только числовые значения. Вы же указали формат настройки через php.ini. О втором способе я знаю, но интересует директива для .htaccess.

Comment: @alexkad Исправил. В интернетах подсказывают, что в литералах тоже возможно, предварительно обернув кавычками, но не уверен.

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
<?php

echo E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE;

?>
```

Возвращает число(decimal), которое можно прописать в .htaccess как

```
php_value error_reporting decimal
```